# Is it possible to execute an IF-condition in a PL/pgSQL function in PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a working function like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(livsm integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  feil text;
  lmrad RECORD;
  colname text;

BEGIN
  -- Test if all mandatory attributes exists
  -- For all rows
  FOR lmrad IN select * from org_sbase2_tmp.ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs where livsmiljo = livsm LOOP
    --For all columns in tmp
    FOR colname IN (select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_alle_lm UNION select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_lmX where livsmiljo = livsm) LOOP
      --If column exists in tmp and is not null, but the column is not mandatory: ERROR - value must be null
      IF colname IN (SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema LIKE 'org_sbase2_tmp' AND table_name LIKE 'ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs') 
         --and colname.value is not null) 
         AND colname in (select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_alle_lm UNION select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_lmX where livsmiljo != livsm)  THEN
        feil = 'Livsmiljø ' || lmrad.livsmiljo || ' and column ' || colname ||' must be empty, but has value.';
        PERFORM org_sbase2_func.mis_registrer_feil_pa_objekt('lmpol', lmrad.ogc_fid,'ban492',feil,'mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner');
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Ferdig med mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I run the function with `select org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(2);`

It works. However, I need to modify it since I need to include something like `and lmrad.||colname|| is not null`. I try with EXECUTE. As a start (just to test the EXECUTE) I use the same code as above (before including the test of the value being null of the particular column in the row) just to try to get all the ' correct:

```
DROP FUNCTION org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(livsm integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  feil text;
  lmrad RECORD;
  colname text;

BEGIN
  -- Test if all mandatory attributes exists
  -- For all rows
  FOR lmrad IN select * from org_sbase2_tmp.ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs where livsmiljo = livsm LOOP
    --For all columns in tmp
    FOR colname IN (select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_alle_lm UNION select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_lmX where livsmiljo = livsm) LOOP
      --If column exists in tmp and is not null, but the column is not mandator: ERROR - value must be null
      EXECUTE 'IF '||colname||' IN (SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema LIKE ''org_sbase2_tmp'' AND table_name LIKE ''ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs'') --and lmrad.'||colname||' is not null
         AND '||colname||' in (select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_alle_lm UNION select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_lmX where livsmiljo != livsm)  THEN
        feil = ''Livsmiljø '' || lmrad.livsmiljo || '' og kolonne '' || colname ||'' skulle vært tom, men har verdi'';
        PERFORM org_sbase2_func.mis_registrer_feil_pa_objekt(''lmpol'', lmrad.ogc_fid,''ban492'',feil,''mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner'');
      END IF;'; 
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Ferdig med mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Now, when running `select org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(2);` it throws an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: IF LDVLAUS302 IN (SELECT column_name from information_schema...
        ^
QUERY:  IF LDVLAUS302 IN (SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema LIKE 'org_sbase2_tmp' AND table_name LIKE 'ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs') --and lmrad.LDVLAUS302 is not null
         AND LDVLAUS302 in (select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_alle_lm UNION select kol_navn from org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_lmX where livsmiljo != livsm)  THEN
        feil = 'Livsmiljø ' || lmrad.livsmiljo || ' og kolonne ' || colname ||' skulle vært tom, men har verdi';
        PERFORM org_sbase2_func.mis_registrer_feil_pa_objekt('lmpol', lmrad.ogc_fid,'ban492',feil,'mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner');
      END IF;
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(integer) line 15 at EXECUTE
```

How may I execute an IF-condition - if possible?

Comment: Possibly you can avoid the cursor loops and IFs, and rewrite the whole thing into a properJOIN and WHERE ([not] EXISTS).

Comment: @wildplasser: Thanks, I managed to implement your idea in a working function. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @wildplasser and @jens-vagts, I managed to rewrite my queries and tests in the function so it works:

```
DROP FUNCTION org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION org_sbase2_func.mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner(livsm integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  colname text;
  sporring text;
  feil text;
  i integer;

BEGIN
  --Hvis kolonna ikke fins i tmp, men kolonna er påkrevd (verdi er enten påkrevd eller opsjon): FEIL - egenskapen mangler
  --Test 1: Check if tmp table is missing mandatory columns (attributes) for livsmiljo X
  --For all columns in tmp
  FOR colname IN (SELECT kol_navn FROM org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_alle_lm UNION SELECT kol_navn FROM org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_lmX WHERE livsmiljo = livsm) LOOP
    IF colname NOT IN (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema LIKE 'org_sbase2_tmp' AND table_name LIKE 'ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs') THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Test 1: Kolonne % mangler',colname;
      feil = 'Test 1: Kolonne som er påkrevd for livsmiljø '||livsm||' mangler: '||colname;
      PERFORM org_sbase2_func.mis_registrer_feil_pa_datasett('ban492',feil,'mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  --Using a temporary table to store result from query, deletes the table if it exits before re-creating it
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS org_sbase2_tmp.tmp_testresultat;
  CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE org_sbase2_tmp.tmp_testresultat (
    testres BOOLEAN
  );

  --Hvis kolonna fins i tmp og er ikke NULL, men kolonna er ikke påkrevd: FEIL - verdi skal være NULL
  --Test 3: Check that irrelevant columns (attributes) have no values (are null)
  --For all columns that doesn't matter for livsmiljo X
  FOR colname IN (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema LIKE 'org_sbase2_tmp' AND table_name LIKE 'ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs' AND column_name NOT IN (SELECT kol_navn FROM org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_alle_lm UNION SELECT kol_navn FROM org_sbase2_func.mis_lovlige_kolonner_lmX WHERE livsmiljo = livsm)) LOOP
    TRUNCATE org_sbase2_tmp.tmp_testresultat;
    sporring = 'INSERT INTO org_sbase2_tmp.tmp_testresultat SELECT '||colname||' is null FROM org_sbase2_tmp.ban492lmpol_5_0_kurs WHERE livsmiljo = '||livsm;
    EXECUTE sporring;
    SELECT count(1) FROM org_sbase2_tmp.tmp_testresultat WHERE testres = false INTO i;
    IF i > 0 THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Test 3: % %', i, colname;
      feil = 'Test 3: Kolonne som IKKE er relevant for livsmiljø '||livsm||' har verdi: '||colname;
      PERFORM org_sbase2_func.mis_registrer_feil_pa_datasett('ban492',feil,'mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RAISE NOTICE 'Ferdig med mis_sjekk_lovlige_lmkolonner';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `IF/THEN` statement available in postgres at all but `CASE/WHEN` as usual in `SQL`. The statement is documented in the chapter [9.17. Conditional Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html).
Even more convenient for your case might be the use of `COALESCE` which tests a column for being null and returns another column in that case as documented in the same chapter of the postgres documentation.

Comment: @Jens_Vagts: Hm, I'm creating a function with IF and it is working without the variable. IF is mentioned here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS.

Comment: Sorry, not that used to PL/pgSQL and used CASE/WHEN and COLESCE until now.

Comment: But nevertheless my answer might point to right direction: according to this issue https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146680/postgres-syntax-error-near-if-when-using-inside-execute the `EXECUTE` supports evaluating pure `SQL` only and `IF` is `PL/pgSQL`.

Comment: @Jens_Vagts: Thanks, I managed to use EXECUTE on SQL in a working function. See my answer above.